# .Net Authentication and Authorization

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have one third party web application developed in the ASP.Net. This web application shows some pdf planning data which comes from the the oracle database.

I have windows authentication defined on this application for authentication purpose. So whenever i first launch this application there is a popup comes up and ask for username and password like this.[image: popup]

I want to get rid this pop up and Instead of entering different username and password each time I want to use a single userid/password for all the hits to this web application. Because I do not want all users to have access to my database.

Please help. I want to use the single username and password without getting the login popup.

Comment: Have you looked at Forms Authentication option?

Comment: As @JonasT says, try forms authentication and maintain a user base in your database.

Comment: forms authentication again we need to enter the username and password. I do not want to give popup or window for username and password.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution i got for my problem We need do the things to get rid of the login popup

1. Set the IIS authentication mode as windows and Use the Active directory authentication.
2. Add the web site as a trusted website in the internet properties.
3. In the internet properties allow automatically login with username and password. It will use your windows username and password and login you.